# unsupported post request. Object with ID 'XXX' does not exist

Tags: express, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> unsupported post request. Object with ID '320278220447428' does not
> exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not
> support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at
> [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22)

hello, I've been trying to post to my facebook page when i add a product into the website using express... im new to coding with the facebook api so i dont know why does this cause an error ... thank you very much !

```
app.post("/products/r", async (req, res) => { // saves the new product from the admin console 
  const newProduct = new Product(req.body);
  await newProduct.save();

  const productName = newProduct.name;
  
  const postMessage = `שלום חברים נוסף לאתר מוצר חדש בשם : `;
  
  const apiEndpoint = `https://graph.facebook.com/${pageId}/feed`;
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(apiEndpoint, {
      message: postMessage,
      access_token: accessToken,
    });
  
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const json = { message: 'Posted to Facebook successfully' };
      res.status(200).json(json);
    } else {
      const json = { error: response.data };
      res.status(response.status).json(json);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error posting to Facebook:', error.response.data);
    const json = { error: 'An error occurred while posting to Facebook' };
    res.status(500).json(json);
  }

});
```

Comment: Are you using a User access token or a Page access token? Does the token has enough permission to publish the content?

Answer (score 0):

you should check the page id in your facebook page and try and send a post request...
also theres a page token and a user token which are totally diffrent.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).